# Differential equations Bernoulli?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $$2y'=x+\ln(y')$$
I want to solve this by Bernoulli but I can't find the right variable to divide this :/ how can I solve this ? I thought about dividing by $y'$,but this is'nt taking me anywhere :/

Comment: Is this written in your notes as Bernoulli, or you think it is Bernoulli? As far as I know this is not Bernoulli

Comment: i think so,no,its not written in my notes.

Answer (score 3):

We want :
$$2\,y'=x+\ln(y')$$
Let's obtain an expression for $y'$ first :

$$-x=\ln\left(y'e^{-2y'}\right)=\ln\left(-2y'e^{-2y'}\right)-\ln(-2)$$
or
$$(-2\,y')e^{(-2y')}=e^{\ln(-2)-x}=-2\,e^{-x}$$
But the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is defined by $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$ so that (for $z=-2e^{-x}$) :
$$-2\,y'=W(-2e^{-x})$$
and we get :
$$y(x)=C-\frac 12\int W(-2e^{-x}) dx$$
$$y(x)=C-\frac 12\left(-\frac 12 W(-2e^{-x})^2-W(-2e^{-x})\right)$$
and the conclusion :
$$\boxed{\displaystyle y(x)=C+\frac 14 W(-2e^{-x})\left(W(-2e^{-x})+2\right)}$$

---

DETAIL of the Lambert W integration

The LambertW functions allowed some authors to rediscover the [Inverse Function Integration](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseFunctionIntegration.html) i.e. following formula for $z:=f(y)$ :
$$\int f^{-1}(z)\,dz=y\,f(y)-\int f(y)\,dy$$
but we won't need this formula since a direct derivation is straightforward.

Let's set $\ z:=-2e^{-x}\;$ as well as $\ w:=W(z)\ $ and $\ z=w\,e^w\ $ and rewrite :
\begin{align}
\int W(-2e^{-x})\,dx&=-\int \frac{W(z)}z\,dz\\
&=-\int \frac 1{we^w}\,w\;(1+w)e^w\,dw\\
&=-\int (1+w)\,dw\\
&=-\frac{w^2}2-w\\
&=-\frac 12 W(-2e^{-x})^2-W(-2e^{-x})\\
\end{align}

Comment: Looks nice, but I think I got lost somewhere in the Lambert W integration details.  Can you tell me what $y$ equals in the first step? I think that's my point of confusion. Thanks.

Comment: @Bitrex: I don't now where you got lost so that I will rewrite/tag the details :

I first put the equation in the form (with $z:=-2e^{-x}$) :
$$\tag{1} (-2y')e^{(-2y')}=z$$
Corresponding to $\ W(z)e^{W(z)}=z\ $ so that $\ W(z)=-2y'$.  
After that I merely integrate : $$\tag{2} y'(x)=-\frac 12 W(-2e^{-x})$$
getting $$\tag{3} y(x)=C-\frac 12 \int W(-2e^{-x})\;dx$$
with $$\tag{4} \int W(-2e^{-x})\;dx=-\frac 12 W(-2e^{-x})^2-W(-2e^{-x})$$
proved in the detail part where I substituted $W(z)=w,\ 1/z=1/(we^w),\ dz=d(we^w)=(1+w)e^w\;dw$.  

What part/transition remains unclear to you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The part I am unclear about is how one goes from $\int f^{-1}(z)\,dz=y\,f(y)-\int f(y)\,dy$ to $\int W(-2e^{-x})dx =-\int \frac{W(z)}zdz$ - the right hand side of these equations.

Comment: @Bitrex: In fact just ignore the first part (I didn't need it after all... the inversion is kind of implicit in $w:=W(z)$ and $z=w\,e^w$ and the first formula is not used but could be deduced the same way I think...).

Comment: @Bitrex: I clarified a little my answer...

Comment: Ah, makes sense now.  Sorry, I'm a little slow today! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem @Bitrex (this part was indeed unclear). Bernoulli lost you but you found Lambert W ! (note that the Lambert-W tag could be added...)